# Sql запрос к нескольким таблицам с конкатенацией (Появляются повторяющееся значения)

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица заказов

table 1

[id, name]

- id - id заказа
- name - имя заказа

Есть таблица, которая хранит какие товары включены в заказ

table 2

[id, id_t1, id_t3]

- id - просто уникальный идентификатор
- id_t1 - id заказа
- id_t3 - id товара

И таблица товаров

table 3

[id, name]

- id - id товара
- name - имя товара

Необходимо вывести таблицу всех заказов. В первом столбце которой содержатся имя заказа, а во втором, через запятую, перечислены товары, включенные в заказ. **Внимание!** Заказ может не содержать товаров. В таком случаи второй столбец пустой.

**UPD 1**

Как писал @Mike группировка помогла, но задача усложнилась.
Добавим еще таблицу клиенты

table 4

[id, name]

- id - id клиента
- name - имя клиента

Предположим, что один заказа могут делать сразу несколько клиентов, и их необходимо также выводить как и товары.

table 5

[id, id_t1, id_t4]

- id - просто уникальный идентификатор
- id_t1 - id заказа
- id_t4 - id клиента

Но когда когда я делаю join с таблицей клиентов (в итоговом запросе 2 GROUP_CONCAT), то получаю что то типа (пример одной сроки, сепаратор `<br>`):

```
Заказ 1      Стол        Алекс

             Стул        Алекс

             Чашка       Алекс
```

То есть, хотя клиент один, его имя дублируется столько раз, сколько выводится товаров. Группировка по id заказа.

Comment: клеите таблицы left join, группируете до заказа и используете group_concat для получения списка через запятую

Comment: join вам в помощь...

Comment: Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон.

Comment: @Anamnian моветон, это держать подготовленный комментарий "на все случаи жизни" и спамить его, дабы показать, что вы якобы что-то из себя представляете. Можно поставить свой "царский" минус и идти мимо.

Comment: если использовать просто join и group_concat (я осведомлен о них), то выводится одна строка. Смысл складывать для каждого товара. Тут нужен под запрос или что-то еще.

Comment: @SanychGoilo это не "якобы" подготовленный комментарий, а пункт справки данного сайта, которую вы видимо не читали.

Comment: @Anamnian поразительно, но это можно применить к любому вопросу на данном ресурсе)

Comment: @SanychGoilo вы в своем вопросе не привели никакие собственные доработки, ни указали проблему с которой столкнулись. Вы буквально написали "сделайте это за меня".

Comment: @Anamnian я не могу приводить наработки, поскольку я не имею права их разглашать. Задача куда обширнее и таблиц куда больше. То что я свел ее к минимуму и есть доработка.

Comment: @SanychGoilo Если у вас после join и group_concat только одна строка, то скорее всего вы не написали по какому полю группировать и в итоге сгруппировалось целиком по всей выборке. добавьте в конце запроса `group by заказы.id` (по вопросу не ясно в какой таблице что, поэтому не могу сказать что точно надо писать). и join должен быть обязательно `left join` что бы выдавались заказы по которым нет товаров

Comment: @Mike дополнил вопрос

Comment: Не дочитал обновлений ... но с запросом все равно было бы проще. да, distinct в group_concat достаточно в вашем случае, но им вы именно подавляете дубли, образующиеся из за не нужного перемножения записей. Если бы у вас рядом с товарами были бы например цены и надо было бы получить сумму, то у вас с такой склейкой возникли бы очень большие сложности. тут уже без подзапросов не обойтись

Answer (score 0):

Все решилось с помощью Group by по id заказа, left join и Distinct

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT com.name SEPARATOR '<br>') as company
```